# Consuming a Web Service in asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, controllers

I need to call a third party webservice from my asp.net web api. The webservice requires authentication and sends an encrypted password on success which needs to be appended to any further requests to web service.issue here is should i create a new instance of webservice in the controller or have one static instance of the webservice that is referenced by the controller.

I am hosting my webapi using OWIN self hosting as a console application.So in my Program.cs I have

```
    public static WebServiceRequests mWebServiceRequest;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";
        mWebServiceRequest = new WebServiceRequests();
        // Start OWIN host 
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
        {
            // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values 
         //   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

          //  var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/values").Result;

           // Console.WriteLine(response);
          //  Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

And my controller goes like

```
public class MFOrdersController : ApiController
{

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        Program.mWebServiceRequest.GetData();
        return new string[] { "value3", "value4" };
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to go about or should it be

```
public class MFOrdersController : ApiController
{
    WebServiceRequests mWebServiceRequest = new WebServiceRequests();
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        mWebServiceRequest.GetData();
        return new string[] { "value3", "value4" };
    }
}
```

The webservicerequest class is as follows

```
class WebServiceRequests
{
    private xstarmf.MFOrderEntryClient mXStarMFService;


    private string strEncryptedPassword;
    private string strPassKey;
    public WebServiceRequests()
    {
        mXStarMFService = new xstarmf.MFOrderEntryClient();

       x
        GeneratePassKey();
        GetPassword("TEst", "test123", strPassKey);

    }
```

I need to pass strEncryptedPassword which I get from GetPassword function in every request (GetData()), xstarmf is a an svcclient

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *have one static instance of the webservice that is referenced by the controller* ?

Comment: Please add to your post what you have tried.